# ¿Cual es la diferencia de usar ++ o - - delante o detras de una variable?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo esta variable:

```
var edad = 22;
```

Aplicamos los operadores unarios: ++ y - - , tanto delante como detras de la variable, de la siguiente forma:

```
console.log(++edad); \\ 23.

console.log(--edad); \\ 21.
```

Si aplicamos al final:

```
console.log(edad++); \\ 22.

console.log(edad--); \\ 22.
```

> ¿Cual es la diferencia entre ellos dos para dar tales resultados?

Comment: si edad = 22; `console.log(edad++)` y `console.log(edad--)` dan 22. Si ahora haces console.log(edad) te va a mostrar 23 y 21 respectivamente. Es decir primero ejecuta el console.log() y luego evalúa la expresión.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Diferencias entre x++ y ++x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376/diferencias-entre-x-y-x). La pregunta enlazada es en Java, pero la misma teoría aplica para otros lenguajes (como JavaScript)

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo ya lo modifique copie y pegue mal jejeje

Answer (score 4, accepted):

te dejo un codigo comentado: revisa los resultados, toma en cuenta las acciones antes y despues

```js
var numero=10;


console.log(numero++);// primero lo muestra, muesta el valor actual y luego lo suma 1
console.log(numero); //muestra el valor actual


console.log(++numero);//primero lo suma y luego lo muestra
console.log(numero); //muestra el valor actual
```