# Diferencias entre x++ y ++x en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, variables-globales, operador-incremento

¿Qué diferencias existen entre estas dos expresiones?

`x++` y `++x`

---

Este es el codigo que estaba intentado entender:

```js
var x=1, y=1, z=0;
do{
    z=x+y;
    console.log("z= "+ z);}

while(++x<=1 && y++>1);
console.log ("++x="+x + " y++="+y);
z+=x+y;
document.write(z);
```

NOTA: He encontrado esta misma pregunta pero respuesta [para Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/376/83) y no sé si la respuesta es correcta para JavaScript

Answer (score 11):

El operador `++` hace los mismo: aumentar el valor.

La única diferencia es que si el operador aparece antes de la variable, el valor se modifica antes de evaluar la expresión.

Ejemplo visual:

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 0;
let i = 0;

while ( i < 5 ) {

  console.log('Variable a: ' + ++a );
  console.log('Variable b: ' + b++ ); 
  
  console.log( 'Iteración #' + i );
  console.log( '-----------' );
  
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Nada mejor que un ejemplo para ver las diferencias :)

Answer (score 9):

`x++` ejecuta la instrucción y luego incrementa el valor.

`++x` incrementa el valor y luego ejecuta la instrucción.

```
var x = 1;
var y = x++; // y = 1, x = 2
var z = ++x; // z = 3, x = 3
```

Answer (score 5):

Tanto Java como Javascript tienen una sintaxis heredera de C/C++, así que sí, el comportamiento es el mismo en todos estos lenguajes: ++ antes indica que el incremento se hace primero, y si se pone después indica que primero se hace el resto de operaciones (comparaciones, asignaciones, paso de parámetros...)

- `f(n++)` es lo mismo que `f(n); n=n+1;`
- `f(++n)` es lo mismo que `n=n+1; f(n);`

Lo mismo aplica a las condiciones o asignaciones:

- `b=n++ > 1` es lo mismo que `b=n>1; n=n+1;`
- `b=--n;` es lo mismo que `n=n-1; b=n;`