# ¿Por qué un valor estático parece ser modificable independientemente de la clase a la que pertenece?

Tags: java

Sé que campo estático no específico a un objeto pero no sé lo que significa en realidad. En particular cuando hizo:

```
public class Static {
    private int value ;
    private static int staticValue ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Static st1=new Static() ;
        Static st2=new Static() ;
        System.out.println(st1.value++) ;
        System.out.println(Static.staticValue++) ;
        System.out.println(st2.value++) ;
        System.out.println(Static.staticValue++) ;
    }
}
```

Me devuelve:

```
0
0
0
1
```

Pensaba que incrementa `value` de `st1` pero persiste con st1 = 0 pero no.

Pensaba que al hacer el primero `Static.staticValue++`, `staticValue`, staticValue, se convertiría en 1 pero no.

Por eso no entiendo por qué finalmente se convierte en 1 con el último `Static.staticValue++`.

Comment: Dime si esto no resuelve lo que vos pensas que esta mal.. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/382/324

Comment: [Aquí tienes una clarísima explicación](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/) sobre las variables estáticas y su funcionamiento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"St1" y "st2" son dos instancias diferentes de un objeto. Además, no tienes inicializada la variable "staticValue", por eso te asigna un 0 en los primeros outputs.

El fundamento de una variable static, es que se puede acceder a ella sin necesidad de crear una instancia del objeto que la encapsula.

Si estuvieras en una clase diferente podrías incrementar la variable "staticValue", de la siguiente manera:  `Static.staticValue++` (Sin necesidad de crear una instancia del objeto "Static").

Ahora paso al código, voy a explicar cada `System.out.println`:

**1)** El primero: Aqui lo que haces es incrementar el valor de "staticValue"de la instancia st1. Al no estar inicizilizado te asigna el valor 0.

**2)** El segundo: Aqi accedes a la variable statica de la clase principal. Al igual que en lo anterior, al no estar inicializada se asigna un 0 en el primer incremento.

**3)** El tercero es lo mismo que en el primero solo que con la instancia st2.

**4)** En este vuelves a acceder "staticValue" de la clase principal. Anteriormente, hemos dicho que está a 0, lo incrementa y, obtienes un 1.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que tenes un error de percepción de lo que tu código esta haciendo.. analicemoslo un poco a ver si entendemos que pasa...

Nuestra clase `Static` viene asi:

```
public class Static {
```

Hay una variable no estatica, o sea que depende de cada instancia

```
    private int value ;
```

Y una variable estatica, que no depende de cada instancia.

```
    private static int staticValue ;
```

Ahora en tu main sigamos el recorrido de cada clase y cada variable

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Hay dos variables de tipo Static (el nombre de la clase, no el tipo de variable)..

```
    Static st1=new Static() ;
    Static st2=new Static() ;
```

Y ahora, empezamos a imprimir... sigamos el recorrido de cada variable al imprimir:

```
    System.out.println(st1.value++) ;
```

Acabamos de imprimir la variable *no estatica* `value`, y despues le sumamos uno [chequea esta respuesta para ver el porque](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376/diferencias-entre-x-y-x).
En este caso, lo unico que se modifico es que `st1.value` ahora si vale 1

```
    System.out.println(Static.staticValue++) ;
```

Acabamos de mostrar y sumar 1 a una variable estatica (ahora si). Entonces esa variable, ahora vale 1 para todas las instancias.

```
    System.out.println(st2.value++) ;
```

Para `st2.value` sigue valiendo 0, por lo tanto ocurre lo mismo que en primer println

```
    System.out.println(Static.staticValue++) ;
```

Y ahora si, como `Static.staticValue` ya valia 1, imprime tu 1, y despues aumenta el valor a 2.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizas el operador `++` despues de una variable, este retorna el valor previo que tenia y actualiza el valor de la variable. Mientras que el operador `++` delante de la variable actualiza el valor de la variable y retorna su nuevo valor:

```
int value = 0;
print(value++);// retorna el valor 0 que era su valor anterior pero value ahora es gual a 1
print(value);// imprime 1 que es el valor actualizado
```

Mientras con el operador pre-increment:

```
int value = 0;
print(++value);// actualiza el valor a 1 y retorna su nuevo valor
print(value);// imprime 1 que es el valor nuevo
```

Por lo que si cambias el orden el operador te funcionara como esperas:

```
Static st1=new Static() ;
Static st2=new Static() ;
System.out.println(st1.value++) ;
System.out.println(++Static.staticValue) ;
System.out.println(st2.value++) ;
System.out.println(++Static.staticValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomando `variable = 0` como referencia:

`++variable` indica *pre*incremento. Esto significa que primero se incrementa el valor de `variable` y después se devuelve su valor, una vez incrementado.

```
System.out.println(++variable); // Devolverá 1
```

`variable++` indica *post*incremento. Esto significa que primero se devuelve el valor de `variable`, y después se incrementa.

```
System.out.println(variable++); // Devolverá 0
```

De ahí que el incremento de valor de `Static.staticValue` solo se aprecie en el segundo `print`.